# Solr pdf indexing issues

Tags: pdf, solr, indexing

I am trying to index pdf with solr with no success. Is it the baseDir and/or url in the datanfig.xml? How do i properly set the above attributes correctly? I am getting the following when i am indexing pdf:
**From Solr:**

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1</int>
</lst><lst name="initArgs">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</lst><str name="command">full-import</str>
<str name="status">idle</str>
<str name="importResponse"/>
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Time Elapsed">0:0:4.231</str>
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">0</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">1</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2012-05-11 18:43:30</str>
<str name="">Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.</str>
<str name="Rolledback">2012-05-11 18:43:30</str></lst><str name="WARNING">This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future.</str>
</response>
```

**The log file:**

```
org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish
INFO: {deleteByQuery=*:*} 0 4
11 Μαϊ 2012 6:55:28 μμ org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to load EntityProcessor implementation for entity:tika Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:264)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:375)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:445)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:426)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to load EntityProcessor implementation for entity:tika Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:621)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:327)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:225)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to load EntityProcessor implementation for entity:tika Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:72)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessor(DocBuilder.java:915)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:635)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:709)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:619)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load TikaEntityProcessor or org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TikaEntityProcessor
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:1110)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessor(DocBuilder.java:912)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'TikaEntityProcessor'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:394)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:1100)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TikaEntityProcessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:378)
    ... 10 more
```

**The data-config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" name="binary" />
    <document>
        <entity name="f" dataSource="binary" rootEntity="false" processor="FileListEntityProcessor" baseDir="/solr/solr/docu/" fileName=".*pdf" recursive="true">
            <entity name="tika" processor="TikaEntityProcessor" url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text">
                <field column="id" name="id" meta="true" />
                <field column="fake_id" name="fake_id" />
                <field column="model" name="model" meta="true" />
                <field column="text" name="biog" />
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**The solrconfig.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<config>

  <abortOnConfigurationError>${solr.abortOnConfigurationError:true}</abortOnConfigurationError>


  <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_36</luceneMatchVersion>





  <lib dir="lib/dist/" regex="apache-solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="lib/contrib/extraction/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="lib/dist/" regex="apache-solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="lib/contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="lib/dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="lib/contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="lib/dist/" regex="apache-solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="lib/contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="lib/dist/" regex="apache-solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="lib/contrib/velocity/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="lib/contrib/extraction/lib/" />



  guration.
    -->
  <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}</dataDir>



  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" 
                    class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.StandardDirectoryFactory}"/>


  <indexConfig>

  </indexConfig>



  <jmx />


  <!-- The default high-performance update handler -->
  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">


  </updateHandler>



  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       Query section - these settings control query time things like caches
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
  <query>

    <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>



    <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
                 size="512"
                 initialSize="512"
                 autowarmCount="0"/>


    <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                     size="512"
                     initialSize="512"
                     autowarmCount="0"/>


    <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                   size="512"
                   initialSize="512"
                   autowarmCount="0"/>


    <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>


   <queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>


   <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>


    <listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">

      </arr>
    </listener>
    <listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">
        <lst>
          <str name="q">static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml</str>
        </lst>
      </arr>
    </listener>


    <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>


    <maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>

  </query>



  <requestDispatcher>

    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" 
                    multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000" />


    <httpCaching never304="true" />

  </requestDispatcher>



  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>



  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">

     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">100</int>
       <str name="df">biog</str>
     </lst>

  </requestHandler>


  <requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

       <!-- VelocityResponseWriter settings -->
       <str name="wt">velocity</str>

       <str name="v.template">browse</str>
       <str name="v.layout">layout</str>
       <str name="title">Solritas</str>

       <str name="df">text</str>
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
       <str name="rows">10</str>
       <str name="fl">*,score</str>
       <str name="mlt.qf">
         text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
       </str>
       <str name="mlt.fl">text,features,name,sku,id,manu,cat</str>
       <int name="mlt.count">3</int>

       <str name="qf">
          text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
       </str>

       <str name="facet">on</str>
       <str name="facet.field">cat</str>
       <str name="facet.field">manu_exact</str>
       <str name="facet.query">ipod</str>
       <str name="facet.query">GB</str>
       <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
       <str name="facet.pivot">cat,inStock</str>
       <str name="facet.range.other">after</str>
       <str name="facet.range">price</str>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.start">0</int>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.end">600</int>
       <int name="f.price.facet.range.gap">50</int>
       <str name="facet.range">popularity</str>
       <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.start">0</int>
       <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.end">10</int>
       <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.gap">3</int>
       <str name="facet.range">manufacturedate_dt</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.start">NOW/YEAR-10YEARS</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.end">NOW</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.gap">+1YEAR</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.other">before</str>
       <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.other">after</str>


       <!-- Highlighting defaults -->
       <str name="hl">on</str>
       <str name="hl.fl">text features name</str>
       <str name="f.name.hl.fragsize">0</str>
       <str name="f.name.hl.alternateField">name</str>
     </lst>
     <arr name="last-components">
       <str>spellcheck</str>
     </arr>
     <!--
     <str name="url-scheme">httpx</str>
     -->
  </requestHandler>

  <requestHandler name="/update" 
                  class="solr.XmlUpdateRequestHandler">

    </requestHandler>

  <requestHandler name="/update/javabin" 
                  class="solr.BinaryUpdateRequestHandler" />


  <requestHandler name="/update/csv" 
                  class="solr.CSVRequestHandler" 
                  startup="lazy" />


  <requestHandler name="/update/json" 
                  class="solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler" 
                  startup="lazy" />


  <requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- All the main content goes into "text"... if you need to return
           the extracted text or do highlighting, use a stored field. -->
      <str name="fmap.content">text</str>
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>

      <!-- capture link hrefs but ignore div attributes -->
      <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
      <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>


  <requestHandler name="/update/xslt"
                   startup="lazy"
                   class="solr.XsltUpdateRequestHandler"/>


  <requestHandler name="/analysis/field" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" />



  <requestHandler name="/analysis/document" 
                  class="solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler" 
                  startup="lazy" />


  <requestHandler name="/admin/" 
                  class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />


  <!-- ping/healthcheck -->
  <requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Echo the request contents back to the client -->
  <requestHandler name="/debug/dump" class="solr.DumpRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str> 
     <str name="echoHandler">true</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>


  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>


    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">name</str>
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">spellchecker</str>

    </lst>


  </searchComponent>


  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


  <searchComponent name="tvComponent" class="solr.TermVectorComponent"/>


  <requestHandler name="/tvrh" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <bool name="tv">true</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>tvComponent</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


  <searchComponent name="clustering" 
                   enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:false}"
                   class="solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent" >
    <!-- Declare an engine -->
    <lst name="engine">
      <!-- The name, only one can be named "default" -->
      <str name="name">default</str>


      <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.lingo.LingoClusteringAlgorithm</str>


      <str name="LingoClusteringAlgorithm.desiredClusterCountBase">20</str>


      <str name="carrot.lexicalResourcesDir">clustering/carrot2</str>


      <str name="MultilingualClustering.defaultLanguage">ENGLISH</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="engine">
      <str name="name">stc</str>
      <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.stc.STCClusteringAlgorithm</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>


  <requestHandler name="/clustering"
                  startup="lazy"
                  enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:false}"
                  class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="clustering">true</bool>
      <str name="clustering.engine">default</str>
      <bool name="clustering.results">true</bool>
      <!-- The title field -->
      <str name="carrot.title">name</str>
      <str name="carrot.url">id</str>
      <!-- The field to cluster on -->
       <str name="carrot.snippet">features</str>
       <!-- produce summaries -->
       <bool name="carrot.produceSummary">true</bool>
       <!-- the maximum number of labels per cluster -->
       <!--<int name="carrot.numDescriptions">5</int>-->
       <!-- produce sub clusters -->
       <bool name="carrot.outputSubClusters">false</bool>

       <str name="df">text</str>
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="qf">
          text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
       </str>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
       <str name="rows">10</str>
       <str name="fl">*,score</str>
    </lst>     
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>clustering</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


  <searchComponent name="terms" class="solr.TermsComponent"/>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the terms component -->
  <requestHandler name="/terms" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
     <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="terms">true</bool>
    </lst>     
    <arr name="components">
      <str>terms</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>



  <searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
    <!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
    <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
  </searchComponent>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the elevator component -->
  <requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="df">text</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>elevator</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Highlighting Component

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters
    -->
  <searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
    <highlighting>
      <!-- Configure the standard fragmenter -->
      <!-- This could most likely be commented out in the "default" case -->
      <fragmenter name="gap" 
                  default="true"
                  class="solr.highlight.GapFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <int name="hl.fragsize">100</int>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- A regular-expression-based fragmenter 
           (for sentence extraction) 
        -->
      <fragmenter name="regex" 
                  class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- slightly smaller fragsizes work better because of slop -->
          <int name="hl.fragsize">70</int>
          <!-- allow 50% slop on fragment sizes -->
          <float name="hl.regex.slop">0.5</float>
          <!-- a basic sentence pattern -->
          <str name="hl.regex.pattern">[-\w ,/\n\&quot;&apos;]{20,200}</str>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- Configure the standard formatter -->
      <formatter name="html" 
                 default="true"
                 class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em>]]></str>
          <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </formatter>

      <!-- Configure the standard encoder -->
      <encoder name="html" 
               class="solr.highlight.HtmlEncoder" />

      <!-- Configure the standard fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="simple" 
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- Configure the single fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="single" 
                       class="solr.highlight.SingleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- default tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="default" 
                        default="true"
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">

      </fragmentsBuilder>

      <!-- multi-colored tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="colored" 
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[
               <b style="background:yellow">,<b style="background:lawgreen">,
               <b style="background:aquamarine">,<b style="background:magenta">,
               <b style="background:palegreen">,<b style="background:coral">,
               <b style="background:wheat">,<b style="background:khaki">,
               <b style="background:lime">,<b style="background:deepskyblue">]]></str>
          <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</b>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </fragmentsBuilder>

      <boundaryScanner name="default" 
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.bs.maxScan">10</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.chars">.,!? &#9;&#10;&#13;</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>

      <boundaryScanner name="breakIterator" 
                       class="solr.highlight.BreakIteratorBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- type should be one of:
               * CHARACTER 
               * WORD (default)
               * LINE
               * SENTENCE 
            -->
          <str name="hl.bs.type">WORD</str>
          <!-- language and country are used when constructing Locale 
               object which will be used when getting instance of 
               BreakIterator 
            -->
          <str name="hl.bs.language">en</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.country">US</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>
    </highlighting>
  </searchComponent>



  <queryResponseWriter name="json" class="solr.JSONResponseWriter">

    <str name="content-type">text/plain; charset=UTF-8</str>
  </queryResponseWriter>


    <queryResponseWriter name="velocity" class="solr.VelocityResponseWriter" startup="lazy"/>



  <queryResponseWriter name="xslt" class="solr.XSLTResponseWriter">
    <int name="xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds">5</int>
  </queryResponseWriter>



  <!-- Legacy config for the admin interface -->
  <admin>
    <defaultQuery>*:*</defaultQuery>


  </admin>

</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Tika you need the apache-solr-dataimporthandler-extras-3.6.0 in the dist directory.

Answer (score 1):

I have indexed pdf & doc files using Solrj library. The following code snippet works:

```
    String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr";

    SolrServer solr = null;

    try {
        solr = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(urlString);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    ContentStreamUpdateRequest up = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");

    try {

        try {
            up.addFile(file);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();}

        up.setParam("literal.id", solrId);
        up.setParam("uprefix", "attr_");
        up.setParam("fmap.content", "attr_content");

        up.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);

        try {
            solr.request(up);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (SolrServerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Once indexed , you can query the "attr_content" (content of the pdf files).